# Big sent socket buffer size cause UDP packet loss

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp, udp, kernel

OS: Centos7.6.10
kernel: 3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64
I use netperf to test UDP.And when I set the sent socket size 8129920;receive socket size 212992,UDP packets are lossed a lot.Only big packets will be in this issue.[two pc netperf test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqSpw.png) And I try to tcpdump,I find that sent UDP data is not complete,always lack one IP frame so that other side can't combine these frame.[tcpdump result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbVXp.png) I use dropwatch on sender PC to find kernel problem,And I find these

```
1581 drops at brk_limit+369bd232 (0xffffffffc0437232)
1 drops at skb_queue_purge+18 (0xffffffff88a235d8)
1632 drops at brk_limit+369bd232 (0xffffffffc0437232)
1682 drops at brk_limit+369bd232 (0xffffffffc0437232)
1732 drops at brk_limit+369bd232 (0xffffffffc0437232)
1 drops at brk_limit+369bd232 (0xffffffffc0437232)
1783 drops at brk_limit+369bd232 (0xffffffffc0437232)
1834 drops at brk_limit+369bd232 (0xffffffffc0437232)
1882 drops at brk_limit+369bd232 (0xffffffffc0437232)
2 drops at brk_limit+369bd232 (0xffffffffc0437232)
1934 drops at brk_limit+369bd232 (0xffffffffc0437232)
1984 drops at brk_limit+369bd232 (0xffffffffc0437232)
2 drops at brk_limit+369bd232 (0xffffffffc0437232)
2036 drops at brk_limit+369bd232 (0xffffffffc0437232)
2087 drops at brk_limit+369bd232 (0xffffffffc0437232)
2135 drops at brk_limit+369bd232 (0xffffffffc0437232)
4 drops at brk_limit+369bd232 (0xffffffffc0437232)
2187 drops at brk_limit+369bd232 (0xffffffffc0437232)
2237 drops at brk_limit+369bd232 (0xffffffffc0437232)
2289 drops at brk_limit+369bd232 (0xffffffffc0437232)
2338 drops at brk_limit+369bd232 (0xffffffffc0437232)
2 drops at brk_limit+369bd232 (0xffffffffc0437232)
2390 drops at brk_limit+369bd232 (0xffffffffc0437232)
2439 drops at brk_limit+369bd232 (0xffffffffc0437232)
3 drops at brk_limit+369bd232 (0xffffffffc0437232)
2492 drops at brk_limit+369bd232 (0xffffffffc0437232)
2544 drops at brk_limit+369bd232 (0xffffffffc0437232)
2595 drops at brk_limit+369bd232 (0xffffffffc0437232)
2641 drops at brk_limit+369bd232 (0xffffffffc0437232)
2694 drops at brk_limit+369bd232 (0xffffffffc0437232)
2745 drops at brk_limit+369bd232 (0xffffffffc0437232)
2 drops at udp4_lib_rcv+b9 (0xffffffff88ab5139)
2795 drops at brk_limit+369bd232 (0xffffffffc0437232)
2846 drops at brk_limit+369bd232 (0xffffffffc0437232)
2898 drops at brk_limit+369bd232 (0xffffffffc0437232)
2949 drops at brk_limit+369bd232 (0xffffffffc0437232)
3000 drops at brk_limit+369bd232 (0xffffffffc0437232)
251 drops at __brk_limit+369bd232 (0xffffffffc0437232)
6 drops at icmp_rcv+125 (0xffffffff88aba7a5)**
```

[the network card info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYPo5.png) I can't understand this phenomenon.I hope you can help me slove this question,Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is expected behavior. Say you send a 65,500 byte datagram and your maximum packet size is 1,500 bytes. That means each datagram requires 44 packets. Now say your packet loss rate is 1%. That means your datagram loss rate 35%. Ouch.

Don't use such large datagrams. Or don't use UDP.

Comment: But I install Centos 7 in vmware and set Consistent configuration.There is no UDP packet loss.

Comment: UDP does not provide reliable transmission, period. That's the nature of UDP. If you can't tolerate datagram loss, don't use UDP.

Answer (score 0):

Linux provides some intra-stack flow control, and setting a very large UDP send socket buffer can short-circuit that. The intra-stack flow control depends on the egress interface having a transmit queue (txqueuelen) large enough to hold more datagrams than will fit within the UDP send socket buffer.  Or put another way, the UDP send socket buffer not be able to hold more than can be queued to the interface transmit queue.

Otherwise, when sending UDP datagrams faster than they can leave the interface, instead of filling the send socket buffer and thus making the socket non-writable until some of the datagrams have left the system, the interface transmit queue overflows and packets start getting dropped outbound.

You will likely see a related statistic in the Udp: section of the output of netstat -s.

What you "should" do is not make the send socket buffer so large.  For UDP it needs to be large enough only to maximize getting datagrams out the interface. 99 times out of 10 (sic) the default should be just fine. What you likely will need to increase in size is the receive socket buffer on the receiver.

Also, unless your application sends 65507 byte messages, you should add a test-specific -m option to tell netperf to send as many bytes as your application typically sends.

As it stands, your making the send socket buffer 8129920 bytes means it can hold 124, 65507 byte UDP datagrams.  When those get fragmented into 44 IP datagram fragments as David points-out that would be something like 5456 packets.  The default interface transmit queue length is 1000 packets...